# Convert this activity to a fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

I would like help to be able to convert this activity to a fragment.

It is a part of a chat in this activity will be the users who are agreed to chat with them, I am not very expert in this language.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_users);

    usersList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.usersList);
    noUsersText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.noUsersText);

    pd = new ProgressDialog(Users.this);
    pd.setMessage("Loading...");
    pd.show();

    String url = "https://androidchatapp-76776.firebaseio.com/users.json";

    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>(){
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String s) {
            doOnSuccess(s);
        }
    },new Response.ErrorListener(){
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            System.out.println("" + volleyError);
        }
    });

    RequestQueue rQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Users.this);
    rQueue.add(request);

    usersList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            UserDetails.chatWith = al.get(position);
            startActivity(new Intent(Users.this, Chat.class));
        }
    });
}

public void doOnSuccess(String s){
    try {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(s);

        Iterator i = obj.keys();
        String key = "";

        while(i.hasNext()){
            key = i.next().toString();

            if(!key.equals(UserDetails.username)) {
                al.add(key);
            }

            totalUsers++;
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(totalUsers <=1){
        noUsersText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        usersList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    else{
        noUsersText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        usersList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        usersList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, al));
    }

    pd.dismiss();
}
}
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After creating fragment class add this to `onCreateView`(just inflate layout instead of `setContent` and `getActivity()` instead of `this` :

```
      @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_users, container, false);


    usersList = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.usersList);
    noUsersText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.noUsersText);

  return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    pd = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
    pd.setMessage("Loading...");
    pd.show();

    String url = "https://androidchatapp-76776.firebaseio.com/users.json";

    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>(){
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String s) {
            doOnSuccess(s);
        }
    },new Response.ErrorListener(){
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            System.out.println("" + volleyError);
        }
    });

    RequestQueue rQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    rQueue.add(request);

    usersList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            UserDetails.chatWith = al.get(position);
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), Chat.class));
        }
    });
}

public void doOnSuccess(String s){
    try {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(s);

        Iterator i = obj.keys();
        String key = "";

        while(i.hasNext()){
            key = i.next().toString();

            if(!key.equals(UserDetails.username)) {
                al.add(key);
            }

            totalUsers++;
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(totalUsers <=1){
        noUsersText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        usersList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    else{
        noUsersText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        usersList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        usersList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, al));
    }

    pd.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: This is a really bad advice. NEVER put any more demanding operations (like API calls) into onCreateView() method! Move it to onViewCreated() instead.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1.** On your `activity_users.xml` put it `FrameLayout` tag

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<...>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    ...

</...>
```

**Step 2.** Create your Fragment as follow:

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import yourpackage.R;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    private ListView usersList;
    private TextView noUsersText;
    private ProgressDialog pd;
    private int totalUsers;
    private List<String> al;

    public MyFragment() { }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my, container, false);
        usersList = view.findViewById(R.id.usersList);
        noUsersText = view.findViewById(R.id.noUsersText);

        pd = new ProgressDialog(Users.this);
        pd.setMessage("Loading...");
        pd.show();

        String url = "https://androidchatapp-76776.firebaseio.com/users.json";

        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>(){
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String s) {
                doOnSuccess(s);
            }
        },new Response.ErrorListener(){
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                System.out.println("" + volleyError);
            }
        });

        RequestQueue rQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Users.this);
        rQueue.add(request);

        usersList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                UserDetails.chatWith = al.get(position);
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), Chat.class));
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    public void doOnSuccess(String s){
        try {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(s);
            al = new ArrayList<>();

            Iterator i = obj.keys();
            String key = "";

            while(i.hasNext()){
                key = i.next().toString();

                if(!key.equals(UserDetails.username)) {
                    al.add(key);
                }

                totalUsers++;
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(totalUsers <=1){
            noUsersText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            usersList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else{
            noUsersText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            usersList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            usersList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, al));
        }

        pd.dismiss();
    }
}
```

**Step 3.** In your `activity Users` put the `MyFragment` as follow:

```
FragmentManager fragMan = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = fragMan.beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.container, new MyFragment());
transaction.commit();
```

It's all. Your Activity it's a Fragment now